# Undefined name '$pb' used as an annotation

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

Generated .pbgrpc.dart has below code,

@$pb.GrpcServiceName('')
class Client extends $grpc.Client {

Error - Undefined name '$pb' used as an annotation. Try defining the name or importing it from another library.

My dart version is 3.0.5 and
protoc is 23.3

Can you please let me know what is being missed.

Comment: You appear to not have [`protobuf`](https://pub.dev/packages/protobuf) (runtime) library.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/google/protobuf.dart/issues/844

if [protoc_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/protoc_plugin) is still not released in version 21.0.1 you can install fix from repo

```
dart pub global activate --source git https://github.com/google/protobuf.dart --git-path protoc_plugin
```

Comment: thank you for the note, but it did not seem to fix the issue even after using the source on git as indicated, might have to wait for new grpc with protobuf 3.0?

Comment: I have `grpc: ^3.2.1`, `protobuf: ^3.0.0` and `protoc_plugin: 21.0.1`. If I remember correctly it didn't work straight away at first. What helped was `flutter clean` or `flutter pub cache clean`.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, the issue was resolved in later version of grpc package, currently on grpc 3.2.4 and all seems fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).